# SpringBoot Page redirection error on controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've tried a lot, but I can't find a reason, so I'm registering a question.
The following three examples are the output results according to the input.
'login_success' and 'login_failed' are both html pages in the template path.

The method 'loginSuccess()' or 'loginFailed()' was not executed in the failed debug result.
What's wrong with that? I need a hand..... ;(

Ex 1) (Successfully Run)

```
[input value] (Query values that are not in DB)
id = abc
password = 1234

[Expected output results]
redirect:login_failed

[Actual output results]
redirect:login_failed
```

Ex 2) (Failed Run)

```
[input value] (Query values that are not in DB)
id = abc@1234
password = abcd1234

[Expected output results]
redirect:login_failed

[Actual output results]
Redirection does not appear.
```

Ex 3) (Failed Run)

```
[input value] (Query values that exist in DB)
id = hihello1234@naver.com
password = byebye0000

[Expected output results]
redirect:login_success

[Actual output results]
Redirection does not appear.
```

And the following code is the logic of receiving View's customer information from the controller as DTo and querying it from the internal logic.

Controller

```
package My_Project.integration.controller;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.LoginDto;
import My_Project.integration.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {


    @Autowired
    private
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/trylogin")
    public String login(LoginDto loginDto) {
        try {
            if (userService.login(loginDto)) {
                return "redirect:/loginSuccess";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/loginFailed";
        }
        return "redirect:/loginFailed";
    }

    @GetMapping("/loginSuccess")
    public String loginSuccess() throws Exception {
        return "login_success";
    }

    @GetMapping("/loginFailed")
    public String loginFailed() throws Exception {
        return "login_failed";
    }
    // 예외처리가 잘못된듯?....
}
```

Service

```
package My_Project.integration.service;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Dto.LoginDto;
import My_Project.integration.entity.Users;
import My_Project.integration.repository.UsersRepository;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    public boolean login(LoginDto loginDto) throws Exception {
        return usersRepository.checkUserInfo(loginDto.getId(), loginDto.getPassword());
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package My_Project.integration.repository.UserCustom.Impl;

import My_Project.integration.entity.Users;
import My_Project.integration.repository.UserCustom.UserCustomRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserCustomRepositoryImpl implements UserCustomRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public boolean checkUserInfo(String id,String password) throws Exception{
        Optional<Users> matchedUser = Optional.ofNullable(em.createQuery("select u from Users u where u.id = :id", Users.class)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getSingleResult());

        if (matchedUser.isPresent() || matchedUser.isEmpty()) {
            if(matchedUser.get().getPassword().equals(password)) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue in UserCustomRepositoryImpl Class, **you are calling .get() even when matchedUser is empty** which might be causing the problem. Separate both cases i.e. when the user is present and when it isn't and handle them accordingly.

When matchedUser is empty you can directly return a false. **Also use the try-catch block here to check issue is here or not. In catch use Sysout to see the error.**

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to fix the Repository? I want to see the code of someone who is better than me

Comment: https://www.javaguides.net/2021/07/spring-boot-tutorial-for-beginners.html

refer to the above guide he has covered everything from basics you will get an idea of working with different calls. He has built everything using JPArepository which is the only issue.

Comment: For a failed run, Repository and Service operate to hand over the return value to the controller, but the controller's return is not performed (debugging mode ends at redirect).